# Could not connect to display tower:10.0

Tags: ssh, x11-forwarding

Got a tower with /etc/ssh/sshd_config like following:

```
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalhost no
```

when I connect to it with ssh with my laptop with following .ssh/config file

```
Host=*
Compression=yes
ForwardAgent=yes
ForwardX11=yes
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-dss
```

I got this debugging options

```
debug2: x11_get_proto: /usr/bin/xauth  list :0 2>/dev/null
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
debug2: channel 0: request x11-req confirm 1
debug2: X11 forwarding request accepted on channel 0
```

And got by default this $DISPLAY variable

```
tower:10.0
```

When I try to run a GUI application I got following error:

```
pg@pipoTower: ~$ kate
debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype x11 rchan 4 win 65536 max 16384
debug1: client_request_x11: request from 127.0.0.1 58798
debug2: fd 7 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 1: new [x11]
debug1: confirm x11
debug2: X11 connection uses different authentication protocol.
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
debug2: X11 rejected 1 i0/o0
debug2: channel 1: read failed
debug2: channel 1: close_read
debug2: channel 1: input open -> drain
debug2: channel 1: ibuf empty
debug2: channel 1: send eof
debug2: channel 1: input drain -> closed
debug2: channel 1: write failed
debug2: channel 1: close_write
debug2: channel 1: output open -> closed
debug2: X11 closed 1 i3/o3
debug2: channel 1: send close
debug2: channel 1: rcvd close
debug2: channel 1: is dead
debug2: channel 1: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 1: free: x11, nchannels 2
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display pipoTower:10.0
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I tried `xhost +` on tower(host) & to set $DISPLAY variable to IP of my laptop which is `export DISPLAY='192.168.178.25:0.0'` still got the same error anybody does have clue what I'm missing?

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of your ssh_config settings? I've never found it necessary to modify X11 settings on the client side in order to simply forward X applications.

Comment: Client side: I understood that with this option you dont need the -X option on client side isn't it? did you mean sshd_config no? There were options I tried after looking on the web...